# Bash 3.2.57 brace expansion {01..09}

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I'm having a little issue, I can't go for bash v.4 I'm stick to use bash 3.2.57.
I'm inputting my script in this form `logs_logs_2017-04-{02..06}.tar.bz2` but since bash 3.2.57 doesn't support brace expansion with leading zeroes the script is feeded with the following `logs_logs_2017-04-2.tar.bz2 logs_logs_2017-04-3.tar.bz2 .....` and these file names don't exist.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Go around the leading zero:

```
somecmd logs-0{2..9}.tar.bz2  logs-{10..15}.tar.bz2
```

(The `02..06` in the example is trivial to handle in this way.)

Or use `printf`:

```
somecmd $(printf "logs-%02d.tar.gz " {2..15})
```

That relies on word-splitting, and works only as long as the file name doesn't have glob characters or whitespace.

Properly done, this would be straightforward, but a bit long:

```
files=()
for x in {2..15} ; do
    files+=( "$(printf "logs-%02d.tar.gz" $x)" )
done
somecmd "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Or use `seq` with a custom `-f` format string.